# How do I change the buffer amount in MediaElement.js?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, mediaelement.js

We have quite the slow network, so I would like to change the percentage/time that mediaelement.js preloads before playing a video.

So for example, it seems to load about 5% before it starts playing, I would like to bump it out to about 15% as the video "catches" the buffered video.

I have flicked through the code, but can't see a glaringly obvious variable or setting that influencing how much is preloaded before kicking off.

Answer (score -3):

Change file: wp-includes/media.php
Change preload value to none

```
    $default_types = wp_get_video_extensions();  
    $defaults_atts = array(  
    'src'      => '',  
    'poster'   => '',  
    'loop'     => '',  
    'autoplay' => '',  
    //'preload'  => 'metadata',  
    'preload'  => 'none',
    'height'   => 360,  
    'width'    => empty( $content_width ) ? 640 : $content_width,  
    );
```